# Solve the following problem....

Tags: euclidean-geometry

My problem is:

In a circle of radius $R$ is inscribed an equilateral triangle $ABC$. Through the point $C$ is drawn a line which intersects $AB$ in point $M$ and the circle, for the second time, in point $N$. Determine $CM\cdot CN$.

My idea is somehow to use sine theorem. So I wrote $CM$ as a function of $R$. But know I got stuck at finding $CN$ also as a function of $R$.

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: I need just a hint!

Comment: The line drawn from C is any line that intersects AB and the circle ?

Comment: The product will depend on where on AB M is.

Comment: T_O@  YES it is just an arbitrary line

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to give the expression of the product depending on some parameter, like the position of M on AB, or the angle $\hat{ACM}$ ?

Comment: I am not sure  .

Comment: @JohnG. this is *purely speculation* but $M$ might be the mid-point of $AB$. also if this is homework, do you know what answer you're supposed to get?

Comment: @Sabyasachi semi-unrelated but what is the length of AB given R ?

Comment: @Sabyasachi So do I have to consider M as the mid-point AB? IN my problem is only written that the line intersects AB in M and that's all.

Comment: @T_O $\frac32 R = a\sqrt{\frac52}$ if I remember my geometry.

Comment: @Sabyasachi No I don't have the result for this problem. It would be much more easier if I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the picture below you can find two similar triangles, one containing another.

> Triangles $CBM$ and $CNB$ are similar because $\angle CBM = \angle CNB$ and $\angle BCM$ is the common angle.

After you write down proportions of the sides of those triangles you will see that $CM\cdot CN$ doesn't really depend on the position of point $M$ on $AB$. It also should give you a simple formula for $CM\cdot CN$ as a function of $BC$.

> $CM\cdot CN = a^2$ where $a$ is the length of the side of $\triangle ABC$.
>  It follows from $\dfrac{CM}{CB} = \dfrac{CB}{CN}$.

It seems that only $R$ is given to you so you have to also express your answer as a function of $R$.

> Note that $BC = a = R\sqrt{3}.$

[image: image here]

> $CM\cdot CN = 3R^2$.

Comment: Frankly , I do not get what are the similar  triangles here.

Comment: @JohnG. I tried to clarify my answer. Do you understand now?

Comment: My another question is how do you know that angles N and B are the same (I mean those represented with green on you graph)?

Comment: @JohnG. That can done in two steps. Firstly, $\angle B = \angle A$ because they're angles of an equilateral triangle. Secondly, $\angle A = \angle N$ because those are two inscribed angles intercepting the same arc.